# How do I retrieve data from JSON file line by line with Json.Net

Tags: c#, json.net

These code generated with Json.Net like this: `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list, Formatting.Indented);` And the results like this:

```
[
  "Apple",
  "Pear",
  "Cherry",
  "Banana",
  "Orange",
  "Grape",
  "Strawberry"
]
```

But I don't know, how do I retrieve these datas line by line to add to List?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Json.NET for deserialization as well!
For your example use:

```
List<string> lines = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(json);
```